# Are there any alternative solutions to "background-attachment: fixed;"?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

When the svg is a static image, I can do it like this:

```css
#clip {
    /* URL: svg>rect[fill=#0008 rotate=45] */
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHdpZHRoPSI1Ni41NiIgaGVpZ2h0PSI1Ni41NiI+PHJlY3Qgd2lkdGg9IjQwIiBoZWlnaHQ9IjQwIiBmaWxsPSIjMDAwOCIgdHJhbnNmb3JtPSJ0cmFuc2xhdGUoMjguMjgsMCkgcm90YXRlKDQ1KSIvPjwvc3ZnPg==");
    background-size: 50vw;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

```html
<main>
    <div id="clip">
        Placeholder<br/>
        Placeholder<br/>
        Placeholder<br/>
        Placeholder<br/>
        Placeholder<br/>
        Placeholder<br/>
        Placeholder<br/>
        Placeholder<br/>
    </div>
    Placeholder<br/>
    Placeholder<br/>
    Placeholder<br/>
    Placeholder<br/>
    Placeholder<br/>
    Placeholder<br/>
    Placeholder<br/>
    Placeholder<br/>
</main>
```

Now next step is making those svg in the background animate. but if I need to change it, I need to make it out of the background, then `background-attachment: fixed` will stop working.

I'm looking for a way to keep both the box clip and animation. I've been trying for days. But I never got one.

I think injecting js into svg or `overflow: hidden;` are potential methods. But js seems to stop working in the background svg image, and if I fix svg to the background with `position: fixed;`, it will jump out of content flow and stop to be clipped by `overflow: hidden;`